# Xamarin.IOS - Sending SMS from iPhone, message application freeze for some time and message is not send

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have very strange behaviour with my IOS application. Basically this application contains multiple buttons and after click I want to send SMS text message with some command to GPRS tracker. Here is my code for sending SMS

```
    void SendMessage (string command)
    {
        if (MFMessageComposeViewController.CanSendText){
            this.messageController = new MessageComposeViewController();
            this.messageController.Recipients = new string[] { PhoneNumber };
            this.messageController.Body = command;
            //this.messageController.MessageComposeDelegate = new MessageComposerDelegate();
            this.messageController.Finished += HandleFinished;

            this.PresentViewController(this.messageController, false, null);
        } else{
            ShowUiAlert("Alert","It is not possible to send SMS!");
        }

    }

    void HandleFinished (object sender, MFMessageComposeResultEventArgs e)
    {
        DismissViewController (true, null);
    }
```

I had very strange problem with testing in DEBUG mode on iPhone 5 device and currently I have the same issue on the application in App store.

When user click on send message the iMessage screen is displayed with prefiled text and phone number. Problem is that after the modal window with SMS is shown everything freeze for couple of seconds and it is not possible to click on Send button or change text. After some time this is possible, but when the user click on Send SMS in iMessage this message is not send.

Another strange problem is that I cannot see the text messages send from iMessage triggered from my app and normal iMessage app. So I assume that I hace some issue with provisioning profile or distribution profile. When I used adhoc distribution it was working for some time. And also when I used App store distribution profiles for App store it was working for some time, but now it is not working again.

Do you have any clue what can happened this or did you have similar issues?

Comment: Is there any chance the SendMessage method is being called by a thread other than the main one?

Comment: Hi Dimitris. It should be called all times on UI thread, but to be sure I will call the SendMessage from InvokeOnMainThread and see what happened. Also strange is that after iPhone restart it is working again for some time.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. No idea what went wrong. Restarting the phone doesn't resolve the issue. I'm using the version XF 2.5.0.12223